# Using dateRestrict to determinate new cases weekly

Tags: date-range, google-custom-search

I'm trying to get 2 date limits from date restrict to calculate the difference between them.
So for example, I get January 1 and January 7, and subtract the second result from the first one.

Theoretically I should end up with the amount of new references to the given searched words in the week, right?
The thing is, sometimes I get a negative result for this, like -60000. How come 60000 references could disappear from one week to another?
Am i misinterpreting the way dateRestrict works?

my url so far is like:

first query:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=MYSEARCH&dateRestrict=d209&key=MYKEY&cx=MYID

second query:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=MYSEARCH&dateRestrict=d203&key=MYKEY&cx=MYID

The field of the response I'm using is the totalResults.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but there is similar discussion: https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/customsearch/14fw9BG6WJ8/discussion (If you haven't **already** seen that response, of course :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the link you gave me is from my post on that forum haha.